# Parsing row where its column has less than 4 characters

Tags: python, pandas

```
command description
0   A.B.C.D IPv4 Prefix entries to show
1   A.B.C.D/length  IPv4 Prefix mask
2   BVI Bridge-Group Virtual Interface
3   Bundle-Ether    Aggregated Ethernet interface(s) | short name ...
4   Bundle-POS  Aggregated POS interface(s) | short name is BP
```

I am trying to select the rows where the description is less than 4 chars.

I tried

`df.loc[len(df['description']) < 4]`

but it's giving me a `KeyError: False`.

Any help?

Comment: df[df['sentence'].str.split().str.len() <4 ].. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so `loc` is not necessary:

```
df[df['description'].str.len() < 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

While jerzrael's answer is simple and straightforward, I will add another alternative where you can count the characters in the string. Since your column has ASCII characters, you can use `[\x00-\x7F]` for a match. Like this:

```
df[df.description.str.count('[\x00-\x7F]') < 4]
```

In case let's say you want to count the occurences of a specific character, you can replace it with that character, for example let's say `A`.

```
df[df.description.str.count('A') < 4]
```